# Why chdir("~/dev/") returns -1?

Tags: c++, c, unix

In my c++ application I want to change working directory to specified one. But when I specifying `"~/dev/"` as working directory `chdir()` fails and returns -1. Instead it works when I'm specifying `"/home/myusername/dev"`. Why this happens? How can I solve this problem (except of checking if string first charachter is `~` and replacing it with `/home/myusername`)?

Comment: `chdir("$HOME/dev/")` fails too, and for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion of tilde (~) to HOME environment variable is done by bash. That expansion is done before that is passed to chdir command. The bottom line is ~ is handled by bash, not by chdir command. So you can not use it in chdir() function call.

In order to find other kind of expansions (and the details of ~ expansion) done by bash, check [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following to retrieve what `~` is likely to expand to (using [`getpwuid`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/pwd.h.html)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>

// @prefer_env should be TRUE if you prefer the value of the $HOME
//  environment variable over what is stored in the user's passwd
char* get_homedir(int prefer_env)
{
    char *found = getenv("HOME");
    char *homedir = NULL;

    if (!prefer_env || !found)
    {
        struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(geteuid());
        if (pw && pw->pw_dir) found = pw->pw_dir;
    }

    if (found)
    {
        // I would add error checking
        homedir = (char*)malloc(strlen(found) + 1);
        strcpy(homedir, found);
    }

    return homedir;
}
```

Comment: This code does not check the HOME environment variable, which might override the path given in the password entry with a different value.

Comment: @Al Riddoch: I'm always leery of that environment variable, but that's just based on experience. I'll update my code to take either.

Comment: For code running as the user on the user's behalf, with pure user privileges, you should always read `HOME` to give the maximum flexibility to the user. For code performing any kind of authoritative lookup on the user's home directory from a standpoint of elevated privileges, you should always use `getpwuid_r`.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution of `~` like any environment variable falls to the shell. I don't think you can use it in C api functions.

Answer (score 1):

Well the ~ is usually replaced by your homedirectory by your shell when you type it in before the shell invokes any program call (even though a cd is not a program call but implemented in the shell itself).

Anyway: There is no way in C to automatically replace the ~ by your homedir

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers state, the C library does not replace ~ for you. It is done by the shell. You should not assume that the users home directory is /home/myusername, as this cannot be assumed.

The correct way to determine the home directory is to check for the HOME environment variable, and read its contents. It will usually be defined, but in case it isn't you should fall back to using getpwuid() or a similar call to get the password entry for the current user, which will include their home directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try using $HOME instead, ~ is just a shortcut to $HOME.

Comment: Actually the shell will still expand ~ to your home directory if $HOME is not set, so it is not as simple as a shortcut to $HOME.